# ReactJS - Components - Best Practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relative new to react and I need to create a character counter component (**CharacterCounter**) for a input field.

[image]

This question is not specific to this component (character counter) - but is a generic question about components best practices in general.

I can implement in two ways (as far I know - if there are better ways I'm happy to hear about it):

1) Wrapping the component and have the input field as a child - The component will insert the span (for showing the counter) after the input field

```
<CharacterCounter maxLength={50}>
    <input type="text">
  </CharacterCounter>
```

and

```
const input = this.container.firstChild
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() { ... });
```

- advantage: I can have multiple components for the same input - if I need extra functionality (components) for this input.
- disadvantage: If the input for some reason stop being the first child of this component - stop working/ fragile

2) To create a generic component which will render the input and the counter on the render() function

like:

```
<CharacterCounter />

render() {
    return (
        <input type="text">
        <span>{this.state.count}</span>
    )
```

- advantage: Not fragile - not relying on the first child
- disadvantage: Not sure is possible to have other component for the same input - let's say I need another component for tracking every time the user type/ or focus/ or blur the field

What is the best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Surely the second approach is better as it is not directly interfering with DOM elements.

If you wanted to have access to DOM elements, still it's better to use [`refs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

> disadvantage: Not sure is possible to have other component for the
>   same input - let's say I need another component for tracking every
>   time the user type/ or focus/ or blur the field

You will get around that easily just with `props`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use second approach with components with state and then use composition to extend that component or create more  “special cases” of that component.

```js
let {Component} = React;

class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: 0}
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      <input 
      {...this.props}
      onChange={() => {
        let count = this.refs.inputCount.value.length;
        this.setState({count})
      }}
      type="text" 
      maxLength="50"
      ref="inputCount" />
      <span> {this.state.count} / 50</span>
    </div>
  }
}

class FocusInput extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Input 
    onFocus={() => {
      console.log('Focus')
    }} />
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Input />
      <FocusInput />
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```